# How to combine strings to use as php var?

Tags: php, wordpress

While using *Advanced Custom Fields* for Wordpress I got to call some vars using `get_field('my-custom-field');`

I got this code which I would like to store in a function:

```
<img src="<?php the_sub_field('image-1'); ?>"> 
<?php $target_post = get_sub_field('target-1'); ?> 
<?php echo get_the_title($target_post); ?>
```

All I need to replace inside my function is the `-1` to `-2`, `-3`, etc. How can I do this?

I have tried this, which does not work:

```
function imageBlock($fieldID = '1') {
   <img src="<?php the_sub_field('image-$fieldID'); ?>"> 
   <?php $target_post = get_sub_field('target-$fieldID'); ?> 
   <?php echo get_the_title($target_post); ?>
}
```

How can I pass the `fieldID` to the `get_field('my-custom-field-1');` function?

Comment: Just one question: Why using so oftern `<?php ?>`, do it the other way around. just `echo '<img src="'.the_sub_field('image-$fieldID').'">';` and then remove the rest of the php tags, currently your function wont work

Comment: @JOUM No, he's right to come in and out of PHP parsing. You shouldn't be echoing out HTML if there is no logic to decide on what that HTML should be. Also your solution would still not work due to the single quoted string as the argument of the function call.

Comment: @worldofjr The function wont work! See first and second line. And the php tags in line 3 and 4  are not needed, so didnt get you :)

Comment: @worldofjr OK so aways use a tool like PHPStorm, but change `the_sub_field('image-'.$fieldID)` in my last comment :) Thanks @worldofjr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to pass a variable into a single quoted string which will take the literal `$` as part of the string, not the start of a variable. There are two ways to correct this.

Either with;

```
get_sub_field("target-$fieldID"); // double quotes
```

or

```
get_sub_field('target-' . $fieldID); // concat
```

So your function would be;

```
function imageBlock($fieldID = '1') {
    ?>
    <img src="<?php the_sub_field("image-$fieldID"); ?>"> 
    <?php $target_post = get_sub_field("target-$fieldID"); ?> 
    <?php
    echo get_the_title($target_post);
}
```

Having said that, I would split the logic out so that you were just returning the string of HTML like the other functions you're calling;

```
function imageBlock($fieldID = '1') {
    $sub_field = the_sub_field("image-$fieldID");
    $target_post = get_sub_field("target-$fieldID");
    $the_title = get_the_title($target_post);

    return "<img src=\"$sub_field\"> $the_title";
}
```

and you can echo the result, ie;

```
echo imageBlock(2);
```

Comment: What about the _other_ question? ;)

Comment: thanks a lot @worldofjr. I did not know that there is a difference between single and double quotes in PHP!

Comment: Hi @MarianRick if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: @worldofjr forgot about this while testing the code.